# validate object of array of objects using yup Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, formik, yup

I am using yup to validate an array of objects, every object of the array have a specific shape

shape of the array of objects : articles:[{offerId:'',url:'',site:'',imgPath:''}]}
an error message must be displayed under every missing field

I tried this code :

```
articles: yup
            .array()
            .min(1, '${path}  is required (min one)')
            .of(
                yup.object({
                    offerId: yup.number().required('Please enter offerid'),
                    url: yup.string().required('Please enter url').matches(URL, 'Enter correct url!'),
                    site: yup.string().required('Please enter site').matches(URL, 'Enter correct url!'),
                    imgPath: yup.string().required('Please enter imgPath').matches(URL, 'Enter correct url!')
                })
            ).compact((v) => !v.offerId && !v.url && !v.site && !v.imgPath)
```

the error message of min 1 is displayed but the other error messages are not
as well there is an error occured when i am trying to add an article :

```bash
Objects are not valid as a React child (found : object with keys {url,site,imgPath}) if you meant to render a collection of children , use an array instead.
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add the error message as text?

Comment: i edited the question as u asked still not found a solution yet hope you can help